# kafka + what are the advantages of more kafka machines in the cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, rhel

We have the following options in order to design new Kafka production cluster ( based on OS - RHEL 7.9 version )

1. **5 Kafka** brokers with Usable storage per broker: 96,000 GB ( 96 TB )
2. **18 Kafka** brokers with Usable storage per broker: 20,000 GB ( 20 TB )

We can see that the second option is more expensive - **18 machines** ( when disk Kafka storage is 20TB ) ,

When the first option is only with **5 machines** but disk Kafka storage is 96T

But we are wondering what is the best practice from Kafka performance side ?

is it better to be with **18 Kafka machines** with less storage ?

Or to be with 5 Kafka machines with 96TB storage per machine

What are the advantages and disadvantages on options 1 and 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why those are the only two options. Can't you have like 7 or 9 brokers? At that scale, the amount of storage per broker shouldn't matter.

More brokers is "better" in order to have higher network throughput and replication, so storage is not the primary factor.

3 is a good minimum for high availability, but then you cannot lose any, even for downtime during upgrades. Therefore 4 or 5 would be best, at a minimum.

On the other side, 18 is rather high for one cluster without knowing your use case (you can always expand a cluster later)... Instead, you can take those machines and divide it into 2 or many  "failover"/active-active clusters, or use it for some alternative use cases like metrics, logs, rather than strictly application events, or more strict security policies, or dev/prod clusters, etc, etc

Comment: so the range is between 5 to 18 , what is the preferred way to decided about this ?

Comment: There isn't. It's use case specific

Comment: could you explain please why more kafka gives better -  higher network throughput  ?

Comment: Because partitions can be more distributed, therefore more requests can be sent, in total

Comment: if you can I will be happy if you can help me with this Question -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73021580/some-replica-are-not-in-sync-when-installing-scratch-kafka-cluster